# Concatenate multiple columns, with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I want to concatenate multiple columns, separated by `;`, in MS-SQL Server 2008.

The problem that I have is that without the `CONCAT()` I don't know how to handle `NULL` columns and not have results like this `tattoos;comics;;;`

Here you have the script to create the sample data:

```
declare @tbl as table (
    id int
    ,kw1 varchar(15)
    ,kw2 varchar(15)
    ,kw3 varchar(15)
    ,kw4 varchar(15)
    ,kw5 varchar(15)
);

insert into @tbl values
(1, 'innocence', 'graphic novel', 'cartoon', NULL, 'comics')
,(2, 'tattoos', 'comics', NULL, NULL, NULL)
,(3, NULL, 'music', 'cartoon', 'adventure', 'film')
```

And the table:

```
+----+-----------+---------------+---------+-----------+--------+
| id |    kw1    |      kw2      |   kw3   |    kw4    |  kw5   |
+----+-----------+---------------+---------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | innocence | graphic novel | cartoon | NULL      | comics |
|  2 | tattoos   | comics        | NULL    | NULL      | NULL   |
|  3 | NULL      | music         | cartoon | adventure | film   |
+----+-----------+---------------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

So my actual result is this:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id |                Keywords                 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  1 | innocence;graphic novel;cartoon;;comics |
|  2 | tattoos;comics;;;                       |
|  3 | ;music;cartoon;adventure;film           |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
```

But this is what i want:

```
+----+----------------------------------------+
| id |                Keywords                |
+----+----------------------------------------+
|  1 | innocence;graphic novel;cartoon;comics |
|  2 | tattoos;comics                         |
|  3 | music;cartoon;adventure;film           |
+----+----------------------------------------+
```

Query:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;

select
    id
    ,kw1 + ';' + kw2 + ';' + kw3 + ';' + kw4 + ';' + kw5 as Keywords
FROM @tbl
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Tanner is the simple concatenation with `+`, but i edited my question

Comment: helps people to work on a solution and highlight your problems though

Comment: If you concatenate with `+`, a `null` value in any column will result in a `null`, not in `;;`

Comment: I'd redesign the table instead, one keyword per row.

Comment: @HoneyBadger This is what I thought so, but this is the result that I get

Comment: @jarlh Yeah I know mate, unfortunately I can't

Comment: @HoneyBadger mystery solved, I had `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF`, this is why my result wasn't `NULL`

Comment: Why you are compromising in the answer if you are getting exactly what you want. Please choose the perfect answer so that it will be helpful to others as well.

Comment: @Susang his answer solved my problem and btw your solution gives wrong result on first line.

Comment: Corrected, if it was your answer then add `;` at last of every record in your example. BTW I got that solution in the very beginning but we always try to find the exact solution as your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of `CONCAT()` (SQL Server 2008 R2+) you can use `ISNULL()` like so:

```
SELECT 
    t.id ,
    ISNULL(t.kw1 + ';', '') + ISNULL(t.kw2 + ';', '') +
    ISNULL(t.kw3 + ';', '') + ISNULL(t.kw4 + ';', '') +
    ISNULL(t.kw5 + ';', '') AS Vals
FROM
    @tbl AS t;
```

If the column value is `NULL` then the joining of `NULL + ';'` would produce `NULL`, therefore giving you the empty string instead `''`.

For 2008 R2+ you'd use `CONCAT()` like so:

```
SELECT 
    t.id ,
    CONCAT(t.kw1 + ';' ,t.kw2 + ';',t.kw3 + ';' ,t.kw4 + ';', t.kw5+ ';') as Vals
FROM 
    @tbl AS t
```

Both produce this result:

```
id          Vals
----------- -----------------------------------------------
1           innocence;graphic novel;cartoon;comics;
2           tattoos;comics;
3           music;cartoon;adventure;film;
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, I found only the way of getting output exactly what you have mentioned using `CASE` so you can try and use it:

```
SELECT
id,
keywords = (
CASE WHEN kw1 IS NOT NULL THEN kw1 + CASE WHEN COALESCE(kw2,kw3,kw4,kw5) IS NOT NULL THEN ';' ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN kw2 IS NOT NULL THEN kw2 + CASE WHEN COALESCE(kw3,kw4,kw5) IS NOT NULL THEN ';' ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN kw3 IS NOT NULL THEN kw3 + CASE WHEN COALESCE(kw4,kw5) IS NOT NULL THEN ';' ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN kw4 IS NOT NULL THEN kw4 + CASE WHEN kw5 IS NOT NULL THEN ';' ELSE '' END ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN kw5 IS NOT NULL THEN kw5 ELSE '' END)
FROM @tbl
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id  keywords
-----------------------------------------
1   innocence;graphic novel;cartoon;comics
2   tattoos;comics
3   music;cartoon;adventure;film
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
     select ISNULL(kwa1,'') + ';' + ISNULL(kw2,'') from TABLENAME
```